# How to upload different parts of text files to different arrays using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream

In a c++ function,

```
readTextFile(ifstream file, char *stateInitials, char *miles, char *shelters);
```

The stateInitials, miles, and shelters are arrays that i need to read sepereate parts of a text file into. the text file looks like

```
WV 4.5 10
NC 7.2 3
TN 8.2 12
```

containing the state where Appalachian trails located, how many miles it contains, and number of shelters.

I need to be able to read in the State Initials into its own array, its miles into its own array and the same with its amount of shelters. I'm not looking for an entire program explained but i do need the basic idea of how one can do this.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Your text file has explicitly structured information, but you break that structure by putting each information into a separate array. How about using a struct or tuple? Also, prefer `std::vector` over arrays.

Comment: The first argument should be `ifstream& file` - you don't want to copy the `ifstream`.

Answer (score 0):

The task of breaking up a line of text into parts is called "parsing". The rules differ from case to case. For instance, a C++ source is parsed by the C++ compiler, but your example has different rules.

You haven't told us the rules, so we'll leave the details to you. Googling for "parsing" should help you get started.

Comment: that actually has brought about several good examples so far a bit beyond my readability of c++ but helping immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line and put contents of each line in to relevant vectors:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream textFile("myFile.txt");

std::string line;
while (std::getline(textFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string str;
    double a, b;
    if (!(iss >> str >> a >> b)) 
    { 
        break;  // error
    }

    stateInitials.push_back(str);
    miles.push_back(a);
    shelters.push_back(b);

}
```

Comment: that actually would work out very proficiently however and unfortunately i have to upload it all using c style string and the classic fstream library. I can use the while statement in my code that is actually an idea i have yet to try. if you have any idea such as this that wouldnt require vectors i would greatly appreciate it. thanks.